# FBFriendPickerViewController crashing in FB-IOS SDK3.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am working on Facebook SDK3.0 on IOS, i generated Facebook key using [developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com)

```
my App ID/API Key 
165158463618789
```

Login works fine but while using `FBFriendPickerViewController` its getting crashing,

**I used following code:**

```
   FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPicker = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc]     init];
   self.friendPickerController = friendPicker;

   [friendPicker loadData];
   friendPicker.navigationItem.title = @"Pick Friends";
   friendPicker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                  initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                  target:self 
                                                                 action:@selector(doneButtonWasPressed:)];
    friendPicker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                 initWithTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                 target:self 
                                                 action:@selector(cancelButtonWasPressed:)];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:friendPicker animated:YES];
```

**And i am getting crash reason**

> -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3024d0
>           2012-08-07 11:13:12.430 IndusPatient[784:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught     exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>   reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized     selector sent to
>   instance 0x3024d0'    *** First throw call stack:
>           (0x321a888f 0x341fe259 0x321aba9b 0x321aa915 0x32105650 0x320f1f19 0x3210e2cd 0x3210d1ad     0x3210e279 0x37a73fb1 0x37a73e8b
>   0x1a9735 0x1a9bbf 0x31c2fefb 0x31c2efd9 0x31c2e763 0x31bd2f37
>   0x321071fb 0x33e6baa5 0x33e6b6bd 0x33e6f843 0x33e6f57f 0x33e674b9
>   0x3217cb1b 0x3217ad57    0x3217b0b1 0x320fe4a5 0x320fe36d 0x31255439
>   0x31bfdcd5 0xcdd2b 0xcdccc)
>       terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing this problem but now i have resolved it.

### using following method/code, i resolved issue

In AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Add this line

```
[FBFriendPickerViewController class];
```

In your viewController header file add

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController;
```

In your viewController implementation file add in a function

```
if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
    // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
    self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
    self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
    self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
}

[self.friendPickerController loadData];
[self.friendPickerController clearSelection];

[self presentModalViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];
```

so i have not used navigation controller style programming.